# Recovering lost text messages on iPhone

Tags: data-synchronization, iphone

I have just realized that a sync is not a backup. I synced my phone days ago, but backed it up months ago.

Is there anyway to get my synced text message history back?

There was some really important info on there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this [Data recovery for iTunes](http://www.wondershare.com/data-recovery-mac/itunes-data-recovery.html) is what you are looking for but you could give it a try! You could also try [Dr.Fone](http://www.wondershare.net/ad/dr-fone/index.html?gclid=CLfpuayviLMCFaV_Qgod7z8A4w)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Stephen, I don't know if [this app](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) can handle data recovery - i.e. if the phone has been zapped, but it's fantastic at offloading messages, voice and text, and any other data. I've used it during app development to check data structures.

(http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

Comment: They now have a free product too called iBrowse