# Is it possible to retrieve deleted text messages from an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, sms

I have an iPhone 4. My text messages which were NOT backed up were deleted by mistake. Is there anyway to retrieve them?

Comment: which version of iOS are you using?

Comment: also, did you see this? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68703/recovering-lost-text-messages-on-iphone?rq=1

Comment: Using IOS Version 6.1.3. iPhone 4.

Comment: http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-restore-deleted-text-messages-on-an-iphone/3/

Answer (score 1):

I would try the [Decipher TextMessage](http://deciphertools.com/recover-deleted-iphone-text-messages.html) desktop software. The program has a recovery feature that enables you to recover deleted or lost text messages.